# How to get the value type from a record in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function which returns a record: `ReturnType: Record<string, {...<SOME_BIG_TYPE>...}>`, and another function that I would like to accept `{...<SOME_BIG_TYPE>...}` as an argument. How can I grab that type from the record?

I would like something like the following where ExtractedValueOf grabs that value I mentioned earlier.

```js
const function = ({ bigObject }: { bigObject: ExtractedValueOf<ReturnType> }) => null;
```

I was thinking something like `ReturnType<keyof ReturnType>` but this does not work.

Edit: Added a basic example that illustrates my issue.

I have here a function that returns `Record<string, SomeType>`, which is used to call my other function, which takes an argument of `SomeType`. This is all typesafe and how I would expect it to work:

```js
type SomeType = {
  field: string;
  another: string;
};

function sample(): Record<string, SomeType> {
  return {
    object: {
      field: "Hello",
      another: "World",
    },
  };
}

function myFunction() {
  return myOtherFunction(sample().object);
}

function myOtherFunction(sampleObject: SomeType) {
  // something in here
  return sampleObject;
}
```

The problem is, in the place I have defined `myOtherFunction`, I don't have access to `SomeType` directly. I have access to the return type from `sample`, but I can't figure out how to get `SomeType` out of `Record<string, SomeType>`

Comment: Have you tried `ReturnType[string]`? Also a detailed example or link to a TypeScript playground would be helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] that others can copy and paste into their own IDEs to immediately get to work on your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much to h-sifat. I did initially try `ReturnType[string]` before posting, but that evaluated to `never`. Turns out it was because `ReturnType` in my case was either the record **or undefined**. The fix was `NonNullable<ReturnType>[string]`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to.

Typescript is [duck-typed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Just define `myOtherFunction` as

```
function myOtherFunction<T>(sampleObject: T) {...}
```

and let the tranpiler do its thing. If `myOtherFunction` requires the argument's `another` property to be a string then any argument being passed must extend `{another: NonNullable<string>}`.

But if you want to tightly couple the code so that any change in `SomeType`'s definition affects both places independently then your question resolves to: "How can I do static code evaluation when the type definitions aren't available at compile time?"

Or am I missing something?